How to return specific column values based on cell value
I am trying to create a formula that will return the employee names and ID's based on the Skill Name in cell A1 if the employee has a "Y" under that Skill Name. I have tried variations of xlookup, index, match, filter, and IF. I have spent hours googling trying to find something similar with no avail.
Let me know if I need to provide more detail/info
Any help is greatly appreciated!!


=FILTER(A4:A14,INDEX(C4:F14,,MATCH(A1,C3:F3,0))="Y")

@SpectralInstance, as it says in the comment, before you start typing a comment: Please avoid answering questions in comments. The question cannot be marked as answered and this dilutes the value of the site.

Please do not provide an image, You should share data so it will be easier to work.

Similar to @Spectral's answer:
=FILTER(Table1[[Employee Name]:[Employee ID]]; INDEX(Table1; 0; MATCH(A1; Table1[#Headers]; 0)) = "Y")


MATCH(A1, Table1[#Headers], 0):


Looks up the column header entered in A1 within the table headers (Table1[#Headers]).
Returns the column number corresponding to the entered skill name.


INDEX(Table1, 0, MATCH(...)):


Retrieves the entire column (specified by the column number) from the table.
0 as the row argument means all rows are included.


FILTER(..., INDEX(...) = "Y"):


Filters the Employee Name and Employee ID columns (Table1[[Employee Name]:[Employee ID]]) where the selected skill column equals "Y".


Dynamic Input in A1:


By changing the skill name in A1, the formula automatically adjusts to filter based on the corresponding column.


Assuming that the table with the name Table1 is defined for range A3:F14.
